# cocos2d menu ccsprite button can't be touched sometimes

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I can't understand why it works well most time, but it can't be touched sometimes.
It may show the bug when loaded iad/admob sometimes I think.

just like this:

```
mnResume=[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"bt_ps_continue.png" selectedImage:@"bt_ps_continue.png" target:self selector:@selector(menuResume)];
mnStore = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"bt_ps_havearest.png" selectedImage:@"bt_ps_havearest.png" target:self selector:@selector(menuStore)];
mnExit=[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"bt_ps_endgame.png" selectedImage:@"bt_ps_endgame.png" target:self selector:@selector(menuExit)];
//mnResume.anchorPoint=ccp(1,0);
//mnExit.anchorPoint=ccp(0,0);
mnResume.position=ccp(size.width*.5,180);
mnStore.position=ccp(size.width*.5,120);
mnExit.position=ccp(size.width*.5,60);
menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:mnResume,mnStore,mnExit, nil];
//menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:nil];
menu.position=ccp(0,0);
[self addChild:menu];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand about CCMenu is that you should never change the CCMenuItem position yourself, otherwise the area that reacts to touches and the graphics of the menu item may not overlap, giving you the impression that it doesn't work (correctly).

If you need to position each menu item independently, wrap each of them into a CCMenu node and change only the position of the CCMenu nodes.

Comment: no,not animation with menu or menuitems. It don't appear everytime. It rarely.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it loads intermittently suggests that perhaps something else (even something invisible) is intercepting the touch event at times. Check that the frame of your ad unit (or some other on-screen control) isn't overlapping the CCMenuItem.

Comment: How can I check which frame is touched ?

Comment: That can be tough, depending on how far down the rabbit hole you want to go. One way would be to apply touch handlers to all the on-screen elements that report their status when touched. Another (more elegant, perhaps) means might be to try a tool such as [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect)

Comment: I fount that someone have the similar question.http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=895 but not the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

apple's recommended minimum size for user-interactive objects is 44x44 as per user interface guidelines. if your objects are of smaller size - you are lacking in touch precision for user. you should increase the size ob your objects if this is the case.

Comment: No,no,no. This knowlage I can understand. But sometimes the menu item can't feedback anything. it can't active the selector.